Were auroras a rare occurrence before the 18th Century?
Wikipedia's page on auroras says:

A mid 19th-century British source says auroras were a rare occurrence before the 18th century. It quotes Halley as saying that before the aurora of 1716, no such phenomenon had been recorded for more than 80 years, and none of any consequence since 1574. It says no appearance is recorded in the Transactions of the French Academy of Sciences between 1666 and 1716; and that one aurora recorded in Berlin Miscellany for 1797 was called a very rare event. One observed in 1723 at Bologna was stated to be the first ever seen there. Celsius (1733) states the oldest residents of Uppsala thought the phenomenon a great rarity before 1716. The period between approximately 1645 and 1715 corresponds to the Maunder minimum in sunspot activity.

Based on above text, it seems like auroras were rarely sighted by people around that time and when it happens, it was considered a big event. However, the solar cycle (which last for 11 years) passes through the solar maximum (highest solar activity) and at that time auroras become more distinct and more visible. From here:

Generally speaking, the Aurora Borealis will remain very active for two to three years either side of Solar Maximum which effectively means we’re heading into the period of maximum activity.

By that logic, auroras would have happened before the 1800s with the same frequency. So why it was concluded that auroras were a rare occurrence? Were the sightings not properly documented? Or any other reasons?
The Wikipedia article about the Maunder minimum says:

During the Maunder Minimum, aurorae had been observed seemingly normally, with a regular decadal-scale cycle. This is somewhat surprising because the later, and less deep, Dalton sunspot minimum is clearly seen in auroral occurrence frequency, at least at lower geomagnetic latitudes. Because geomagnetic latitude is an important factor in auroral occurrence, (lower-latitude aurorae requiring higher levels of solar-terrestrial activity) it becomes important to allow for population migration and other factors that may have influenced the number of reliable auroral observers at a given magnetic latitude for the earlier dates.

which clearly conflicts with the first quote.
References:

David M Willis, José M Vaquero, F Richard Stephenson, Early observation of the aurora australis: AD 1640, Astronomy & Geophysics, Volume 50, Issue 5, October 2009, Pages 5.20–5.24, DOI: 10.1111/j.1468-4004.2009.50520.x


You may find a better informed community on that subject in astronomy.SE

Note that the historical location of the geomagnetic pole could be a factor.  It seems to have moved southeast during the early 18th century, away from Europe but possibly not enough to affect the visibility of the aurora borealis significantly, whereafter it began to move north, slowly at first and recently much more rapidly.

It may also be relevant that aurorae are easier to see with a long exposure photo than by eye, making them more visible in modern days. On the flipside modern light pollution probably makes them less visible.
